# Is there any Video Rental VOD (video-on-demand) API's out there?

Tags: api, stream, streaming, video-streaming, video-on-demand

I have been searching for this for a while and I can't find. I am searching for a video on demand APi but I can't find any. Please help.

UPDATE:

Let me clarify one thing, I want to rent the movie THE MATRIX via API so I can show it to the user. That is what I pretend?

Comment: This solution depends on the media server which you plan using. What do you use?

Comment: Hum this is a new project I can do whatever. I need a provider that already has the videos.

Comment: Did you succeed? If yes , gimme link please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to look into UltraViolet or Locker Access Streaming Provider Role (LASP).

check out UltraViolet for Business,
https://www.uvvu.com/en/au/uv-for-business

to connect your service to UltraViolet or to Develop Services or components you need a licence.
Download the licence package here: https://uvvu.com/sites/default/files/DECE%20License%20Agrmnts20140820%20PDFs.zip

hope this helps.

Comment: I found the list of content management providers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at solutions called "paywall" or "pay-per-view" for the media server which you decide to pick up.

Comment: I search for the 2 approuches but I am not convinced :) thanks btw.

Comment: Let me clarify one thing, I want to rent the movie THE MATRIX via API so I can show it to the user. Are you sure that both of does solutions do this?

Comment: If you don't own the content, then you should contact to the content providers and ask for available options.

Comment: What are content providers? can you give me an example please?

Comment: It is someone who owns the content or who has the rights for it.

Comment: I see. [I know I am asking to much :)] and 1 example do you know?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We work with media hosting providers and streaming companies, not content owners.

Answer (score 1):

There was a site called Popcorn Time which is similar to Netflix in number of ways. They made their source code available for every one by making the project open source after attracting huge media attention.

Comment: Thanks. Yes but I want to RESELL the movies via api, via VOD. It needs to be legal :)